# static NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

I want to use static NSMutableDictionary. Can you please help how to use static NSMutableDictionary in class.

Is it right way?
.h file

```
+(NSMutableDictionary*)contactsToAssignBill;
+(void)setContactsToAssignBill:(NSMutableDictionary*)value;
```

.m file

```
static NSMutableDictionary * contactsToAssignBill;

+(NSMutableDictionary*)contactsToAssignBill
{
    if (!contactsToAssignBill)
        contactsToAssignBill = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    return contactsToAssignBill;
}

+(void)setContactsToAssignBill:(NSMutableDictionary *)value
{
    if(contactsToAssignBill != value)
    {
        [contactsToAssignBill release];
        contactsToAssignBill = [value mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

Comment: If your class is a singleton, then yes. But why would you do so?

Comment: because I want to use this dictionary in another class without making object of the class wich contains this dictionary

Comment: does my approach for creating satic dictionary is right?

Comment: what is the use of this for making static .. you can alloc this dictionary in appdelegate which has shared object.. !

Comment: I think that for making a class variable, this is as close as Objective-C gets.

Comment: I don't see any real usage. Why don't you create a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right way to do that.  Just bear in mind that the dictionary won't get deallocated at any point.